# Replace 0 with NaN for selected columns only if all values are 0 in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
   id  value1  value2  value3
0   0      22       1       7
1   1       0       0       0
2   2       0       0       0
3   3       4       1      25
4   4       5       0      24
5   5       0       0       3
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 0, 'value1': 22, 'value2': 1, 'value3': 7},
 {'id': 1, 'value1': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value3': 0},
 {'id': 2, 'value1': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value3': 0},
 {'id': 3, 'value1': 4, 'value2': 1, 'value3': 25},
 {'id': 4, 'value1': 5, 'value2': 0, 'value3': 24},
 {'id': 5, 'value1': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value3': 3}])
```

I need to subset columns `'value1', 'value2', 'value3'`, replace `0` with `NaN` if all values are `0`s row-wisely. How could I acheive that in Pandas?

The exepected result will like this:

```
   id  value1  value2  value3
0   0    22.0     1.0     7.0
1   1     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   2     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   3     4.0     1.0    25.0
4   4     5.0     0.0    24.0
5   5     0.0     0.0     3.0
```

Code I have tried:

```
cols = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
df[cols] = df[cols].replace({'0': np.NaN, 0: np.NaN})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].eq(0).all(axis=1))
```

[`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) automatically sets the row to `NaN` if the condition (`df[cols].eq(0).all(axis=1)`) is `True`.

**Original answer:**

I'd prefer `mask`:

```
>>> df.set_index('id').mask(df[cols].eq(0).all(axis=1))
    value1  value2  value3
id                        
0     22.0     1.0     7.0
1      NaN     NaN     NaN
2      NaN     NaN     NaN
3      4.0     1.0    25.0
4      5.0     0.0    24.0
5      0.0     0.0     3.0
>>>
```

With resetting index:

```
>>> df.set_index('id').mask(df[cols].eq(0).all(axis=1)).reset_index()
   id  value1  value2  value3
0   0    22.0     1.0     7.0
1   1     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   2     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   3     4.0     1.0    25.0
4   4     5.0     0.0    24.0
5   5     0.0     0.0     3.0
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, but in real data, besides `id`, if i have many other columns to not replace 0 with NaN, so I need to set them as index, i think code will not be consice.

Comment: @ahbon I added a much better answer! Check it out

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

```
mask = (df[cols].eq(0).all(axis=1))
df.loc[mask, cols] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
   id  value1  value2  value3
0   0    22.0     1.0     7.0
1   1     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   2     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   3     4.0     1.0    25.0
4   4     5.0     0.0    24.0
5   5     0.0     0.0     3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I was trying to figure out the same, and after the preceding solutions didn’t work for me, I found this.

```
df[cols].replace(to_replace=0, value=np.NaN, inplace=True)
```

Hopefully this solution will be useful for anyone who experiences the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing types, your code tries to compare two different data types and throws an TypeError: `TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=float64)' and 'str'`
To make your code work you simply have to remove `'0': np.NaN` from your dict or instead of a `dict` pass two arguments:

```py
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(0, float('NaN'))
```

Comment: I only need to manipulate columns `value1  value2  value3`.